# Nextjs - Implementing next-auth middleware in addition to nextjs middleware

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I need the nextjs middleware to run for two different paths:

- First, to protect against unauthorized access which is achieved using next-auth.
- Second, to redirect authorized users from certain pages e.g. if an authorized user lands on anything under the `auth` namespace, then redirect to them to the dashboard. (I know I can do this on the client, but its much cleaner on the middleware level, imo).

Problem is that it looks like next-auth takes over the entire middleware logic:

```js
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware"

export default withAuth(
  function middleware(req) {
    console.log(req.nextauth.token)
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => token?.role === "admin",
    },
  }
)

export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard/:path*", "/auth/:path*"] };
```

Is it possible to move this logic to a regular nextjs middleware? If not, how is it possible to implement logic unrelated next-auth, but in addition to it?